# Whats the optimal temperature for the Pi's processor to run at?

Tags: temperature

At what temperature will the Pi's processor work fastest?

Comment: Doesn't really matter. CPU speed is based on the 19.2Mhz Crystal oscillator, so it's fixed.

Comment: Even at 0 Celsius?

Comment: Not a problem for the CPU. 0 Degrees C should be fine. But at even lower temperatures you could get problems with the stresses on the solder connections. Solder gets more brittle, and the chip might contract more than the PCB it's on, causing stress on the connections. These stresses could cause broken connections, leading to a malfunctioning Pi. Where are you planning to run the Pi?

Comment: Just at home. I thought that the temperature would affect the Pi's CPU. On my laptop, the temperature really slows it down. See http://superuser.com/questions/588764/how-can-i-keep-my-laptop-fan-on-the-entire-time, which made me think the Pi works the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your laptop it's not the temperature itself that slows you down, it's the processor overheat protection, that lowers the CPU frequency to avoid burning it out.

In case of RPi, the best temperature is the room temperature, with not very high humidity. If you want to make RPi processor run faster, run `raspi-config` and check overclocking options, just don't go too high and stay safe.